# How to parse AWS SNS notification or get the content of notification from SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-kVhzt7X5Kw&list=PLzDD7Ab9wnDC5FfvPSGgSqV7AkFS0TJcw&index=2) by AWS official youtube channel, to sum it up, I set up an email on SES(Amazon Simple Email Service) with my custom domain, e.g. `info@mycustomdomain.com`, I added a rule on that which is publishing the email to SNS topic, then I created a subscription to the topic, the protocol is `EMAIL-JSON`, and all the emails sent to that `info@mycustomdomain.com` will be forwarded to my personal email address, but in a very horrible way, the message format is like this (from [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-large-payload-raw-message-delivery.html)):

```
{
  "Type": "Notification",
  "MessageId": "dc1e94d9-56c5-5e96-808d-cc7f68faa162",
  "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:111122223333:ExampleTopic1",
  "Subject": "TestSubject",
  "Message": "This is a test message.",
  "Timestamp": "2021-02-16T21:41:19.978Z",
  "SignatureVersion": "1",
  "Signature": "FMG5tlZhJNHLHUXvZgtZzlk24FzVa7oX0T4P03neeXw8ZEXZx6z35j2FOTuNYShn2h0bKNC/zLTnMyIxEzmi2X1shOBWsJHkrW2xkR58ABZF+4uWHEE73yDVR4SyYAikP9jstZzDRm+bcVs8+T0yaLiEGLrIIIL4esi1llhIkgErCuy5btPcWXBdio2fpCRD5x9oR6gmE/rd5O7lX1c1uvnv4r1Lkk4pqP2/iUfxFZva1xLSRvgyfm6D9hNklVyPfy+7TalMD0lzmJuOrExtnSIbZew3foxgx8GT+lbZkLd0ZdtdRJlIyPRP44eyq78sU0Eo/LsDr0Iak4ZDpg8dXg==",
  "SigningCertURL": "https://sns.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-010a507c1833636cd94bdb98bd93083a.pem",
  "UnsubscribeURL": "https://sns.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:111122223333:ExampleTopic1:e1039402-24e7-40a3-a0d4-797da162b297"
}
```

I want to parse AWS SNS notification using lambda or get the content from notification in whatever ways, or if you suggest other ways to forward emails from my custom domain email to my personal email address, please leave the comment.

What I have tried:

1. Amazon SNS raw message delivery

I tried to use setSubscriptionAttributes API, and got error msg: `An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the SetSubscriptionAttributes operation: Invalid parameter: Delivery protocol [email-json] does not support raw message delivery.`

2. Amazon SNS subscription filter policies

I tried to add something like `{ "Messages": ["some value in the notification"] }`into filter policies, it ended up with no notifications at all, the notifications format are like   `"Message" : "{\"notificationType\":\"Received\",\"mail\":{\"timestamp\":\"...\}"`, so I used values like notificationType to test, but failed anyways.

3. Lambda

First, I created a lambda function and added trigger to SNS topic, the test sample I used was the one I mentioned from the documentation, it passed the test, but when I sent emails to that custom domain email address, the notifications I received did not change, then I added `Invoke Lambda function` into the rule set on SES, it still didn't work.

I wonder which way should I proceed, and if you can give me any guidance or help, I would very appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I’ve managed to solve the issue on my own. Instead of publishing the email to SNS topic in the rule set, I decided to just use `Invoke Lambda function`. I then subscribed a lambda function to the SNS. In this function, I decoded and parsed the JSON to extract the content I needed. The key step was to use `client-ses` from `aws-sdk` in the lambda function, which allowed me to send the content to the desired email address via SES. But I think this is definitely not the best method, going from SES to lambda, then to SNS, and back to SES, it's quite bothersome. If anyone has a more streamlined approach, welcome to share.